# Moving a sprite in 2D matrix array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, 2d, maze

I have created a 2D array which contains a 10 x 10 maze. The problem I am having now is how I will move the sprite on the maze jpg (when it's actually working on the table).

How would I move the sprite a specific distance to make it appear as if it is moving to the next square?

I have about they keyboard functions and think I would need this code. But I am confused about the logic on moving the sprite a specific square.

```
PlayerX = 1   
PlayerY = 1             

Up =   MazeArray[PlayerX, PlayerY - 1];

Down = MazeArray[PlayerX, PlayerY + 1];

Left = MazeArray[PlayerX - 1, PlayerY];

Right= MazeArray[PlayerX + 1, PlayerY];
```

Comment: What are you using to draw the sprite? `canvas`, `div`, `img`?

Comment: <canvas id="canvas" width="60px" height="60px" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JAVASCRIPT">
   
   Canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
   MyCanvas = Canvas.getContext("2d");
   MyCanvas.beginPath();                       
   MyCanvas.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 162, 232)";  
   MyCanvas.arc(30, 30, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true); 
   MyCanvas.stroke();                           
   MyCanvas.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 162, 232)";  
   MyCanvas.fill();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canvas should contain the whole maze and your character sprite.

Your sprite is a circle with radius 10 (so it's 20px by 20px) but a "square" of your maze is only 6px by 6px (because your canvas is 60px by 60px and you said the maze is 10x10).

To make it look like it moves a square away you need to make it first fit one cell.
Make your canvas bigger (200px by 200px if you want to keep a 10px radius).

Then you can specify it's position when you draw the sprite:

```
PlayerX=4; // 0 <= PlayerX < 10
PlayerY=5; // 0 <= PlayerY < 10
MyCanvas.arc(10+PlayerX*20, 10+PlayerY*20, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to get it to work. I did need to add the MyCanvas.arc code again 

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it greatly!